# Has anybody tried the new MVC HTML5 Toolkit from Codeplex?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html, codeplex

I saw a [tweet](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+html5) today referring to the [MVCHTML5](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29) helpers on [Codeplex](http://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/).  I'm wondering if

1. Anybody has tried this out yet?
2. Does it add any real significant benefit over the default HTML helpers?
3. What are the actual *HTML5* aspects of this library?

Comment: honestly I don't really fully understand all the new fandangled stuff that comes with HTML5 other than some of the nice embedded video stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend checking it (I am a little biased as I wrote it!).
But it's just a simple DLL that you include in your MVC project and it will give you all the benefits of HTML5 input types. If the browser doesn't support it - it will just fall back to a normal textbox.

To answer your questions though, it only adds a benefit if you are looking to add HTML5 functionality to your application or website. It uses the exact same syntax and the normal HTML helpers that ASP.net MVC comes with, but this just makes life easier if you are looking to add HTML5 functionality to your site.

Here is another link regarding HTML5 and the input types: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/

Answer (score 0):

I've just been trying it out, it doesn't seem to support the Required DataAnnotations for unobtrusive client side validation